# Do you need Rum or Sugar for anything?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassins Creed: Black Flag, I was wondering what Rum and Sugar are for because I just sell it, is there any other reason for the rum & sugar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No you dont need it. It can only be sold

Comment: Surely then you need it to make money?

Comment: It's one way of making money.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. It's just there to help you with some money (by selling it).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually used to trade in Kenways fleet

Comment: Only those that you find in "Kenway's fleet", which is not what this question is about.